# How to set up a boolean in a user menu?

Tags: java, boolean

I'm trying to set up a boolean flag so that the user must enter 'M' (Mark the student answers) before they are able to choose 'S' and 'Q'. If they choose these, there should be a message saying "Please mark the answers before inputting statistics". The rest of the options should always be available for the user but I'm not sure how to set up a boolean so that the user must choose 'M' before choosing 'S' and 'Q'. Anyone know how to do this? Here is my code so far:

```
   public class Marker_Menu
   {
       public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
       {
           Quiz_Marker input2 = new Quiz_Marker();
           char arg[]= null;

           System.out.println ("Welcome to the Quiz Grading System \n");

           char choice = menu();
           while(choice != 'E')
           {
               switch (choice)
               {
                   case 'C':
                   input2.corAnsPrint();
                   break;

                   case 'A':
                   input2.stuAnsPrint();
                   break;

                   case 'M':
                   input2.quizMarking();
                   break;

                   case 'S':
                   input2.stuStatsPrint();
                   break;

                   case 'Q':
                   input2.quesStatsPrint();
                   break;

                   default:
                   System.out.println("Your choice is invalid");
            }
            choice = menu();
        }
        System.out.println("Thank you for using the Quiz Marker System");
        System.exit(0);        
    }

    public static char menu() throws IOException
    {


        System.out.println ("Please enter your choice \n" +
            "   C - Print Correct Answers \n" +
            "   A - Print Student Answers \n" +
            "   M - Mark the Student Answers \n" +
            "   S - Produce the Quiz Statistics \n" +
            "   Q - Produce Question Statistics \n" +
            "   E - Exit the System");

        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        char choice = input.next().toUpperCase().charAt(0);

        return choice;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a boolean variable, set it when `'M'` is selected, and test it if `'S'` or `'Q'` is selected:

```
public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
{
    boolean mSelected = false;

    ...

    while(choice != 'E')
        {
        switch (choice)
        {
            ...

            case 'M':
            mSelected = true;
            input2.quizMarking();
            break;

            case 'S':
            if (mSelected) {
                input2.stuStatsPrint();
            } else {
                System.out.println("Please mark the answers before inputting statistics");
            }
            break;

            case 'Q':
            if (mSelected) {
                input2.quesStatsPrint();
            } else {
                System.out.println("Please mark the answers before inputting statistics");
            }
            break;

            ...
        }

    ...
```